# AWS SageMaker Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I started to work with AWS SageMaker. I have an AWS Starter Account. I have been trying to deploy a built-in algorithm for 2 days but I always get `AccessDeniedException` despite the fact that I created IAM role according to https://aws.amazon.com/tr/getting-started/tutorials/build-train-deploy-machine-learning-model-sagemaker/

> ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the CreateTrainingJob operation: User: arn:aws:sts::161745376217:assumed-role/AmazonSageMaker-ExecutionRole-20200203T194557/SageMaker is not authorized to perform: sagemaker:CreateTrainingJob on resource: arn:aws:sagemaker:us-east-1:161745376217:training-job/blazingtext-2020-02-03-18-12-14-017 with an explicit deny

Could you help me to solve this problem ?
Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created a role for SageMaker to access S3 bucket, but it seems your IAM user doesn't have access to SageMaker service. Please make sure your IAM user has permission to SageMaker.

Comment: When i try to create new IAM role,it doesnt give me right to login via that user. I think it is a policy for student accounts .Normally student account has a permission to use sagemaker but i cant do that

Comment: This is it, you don't have permission to use sagemaker. Ask your teacher/AccountAdmin to provide you that access.

Answer (score 1):

This error usually occurs, if you have an `AWS Educate` account. It restricts you to take full control of the Sagemaker service. In this case, I'd recommend you to access AWS using regular AWS account.